# Track impressions from image src tag

Tags: php, html

I need to include an image tag that references a script:

```
<img src="http://the.site./script.php"/>
```

But I'm not sure of how to make this invisible. Sort of behind the scenes to track impressions.

2 Questions:

1. How do I properly layout the  tag?
2. What would script.php contain?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Does script.php return an image?

Comment: No, script.php is just for tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it into a [web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) - the script could return a 1x1 transparent GIF image (create a 1x1 transparent GIF and save it on your server):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
// whatever tracking/data mining you want to do with the data, do that here.
readfile('your_1x1_file.gif');
exit;
?>
```

Note that this is the technical side of things, the legal part on web tracking etc. is up to you (and your company's legal dept.)

Answer (score 10):

Place your img element at the end of the page.

```
<img src="http://the.site./script.php?foo=bar&baz=quux" width="1" height="1"/>
</body>
```

Then in PHP, you can track the hit in a database. I assume you already know how to do that; if not, you can find more information about accessing a database from PHP on the Internet.

The only thing left is to return the image that the browser is expecting. You can do so using this code, which returns a 1x1 pixel transparent GIF image:

```
<?php

// Tracking code goes here

// Output a 1x1 transparent GIF
header('Content-type: image/gif');
echo base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7');
```

Comment: This is great. This is probably definitely faster than hitting the filesystem for a 1x1 gif right?

Answer (score 6):

script.php would contain a code that updates a tracking database with a single hit. Then it outputs a small, empty image (1 pix width and 1 pix height transparent).

This way you will know the user has visited the page, while the user won't see the image.